# Duda con URLs amigables en PHP

Tags: php, php7

He generado una tabla que muestra los registro de la base de datos. Uno de esos registros es un `href`, el cual te redirecciona a otra página llamada `mostrardatos.php`.

El problema es que en el `href` del HTML tuve que colocar la rutas de la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo que me mostrara los datos solicitados y, al generar el enlace, me sale la ruta de la carpeta completa.

La tabla mostraría  **"esto es un registro"** esa frase seria el enlace.

Ella se muestran de la siguiente manera en el navegador `includ/funcion/enfermedad/mostrardatos.php?id=1` y esa ruta tuve que colocarla en el `href` de mi HTML de la siguiente manera:

**esto se encuentra en el achivo tablaenfermedad.php**

```
<a href="includ/funcion/enfermedad/mostrardatos.php?id=<?php echo $ROWS['enfermedad_id']; ?>">
```

**archivo aparte**
Y en el archivo `datosenfermedad.php` coloqué lo siguiente:

```
$id= mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, $_GET['id']);
```

Lo que me gustaría mostrar en el navegador es lo siguiente:

```
localhost/mipagina/mostrardatos.php/estoesunregistro
```

En el archivo `mostrardatos.php` coloqué este código:

```
$id= mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, $_GET['id']);
```

Con eso él me lee el campo `GET` del `href` y me muestra los datos seleccionados en el enlace de la tabla.

```
<?php 


function generarUrl($texto)
{
    /* Transliteramos los caracteres no ASCII */
    $texto = iconv(
        "UTF-8",
        "ASCII//TRANSLIT",
        $texto
    );
    /* Eliminamos cualquier carácter no alfanumérico */
    $texto = preg_replace("#[^\d\w]#", " ", $texto);
    /* Eliminamos espacios en blanco repetidos */
    $texto = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $texto);
    /* Convertimos los espacios en guiones (o guiones bajos) */
    $texto = str_replace(" ", "-", trim($texto));
    /* Devolvemos la cadena en minúsculas y sin espacios */
    return strtolower($texto);
}

  $results=$bd->query("SELECT * from enfermedad");
$resulta=mysqli_fetch_array($results);





$url = "includ/funcion/enfermedad/mostrardatos.php/"
    . htmlspecialchars($resulta["enfermedad_id"]) ."/"
    . htmlspecialchars(generarUrl($resulta["nombre_enfermedad"]));




 ?>

<boddy>
      
      <table class="table table-bordered">
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><label >Nombre Pasiente</label></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><label >Nombre de la enfermedad </label></th>


           <?php if (isset($_SESSION['rol']) && !empty($_SESSION['rol'])) { ?>

              <th scope="col" colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><label >Accion</label></th>

              <?php } ?>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody> 
                      
                            <?php 
                            while ($ROWS=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                              ?>

                              <tr>
                                <th scope="col" style="text-align:center">

                                   <?php echo $ROWS['nombre_enfermo'];?>
                                 
                                               
                                </th>
                               
               <th scope="col" style="text-align:center" class="bdatos"><a href="<?php $url; ?>" id="<?php echo $ROWS['enfermedad_id'];?>"><?php echo $ROWS['nombre_enfermedad'];?></a>

               </th>
                 
                               
                  <th class="center">


   }
?>
                </tr>
</tbody>
</table>





        <div id="regist_solicitud"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tras proporcionar más detalles en los comentarios procedo a redactar una respuesta más específica.

### Generar una URL amigable

Para generar una URL amigable lo primero que tenemos que hacer es normalizar cualquier texto de manera que pueda incluirse en la URL sin necesidad de conversión a entidades:

```
function generarUrl($texto)
{
    /* Transliteramos los caracteres no ASCII */
    $texto = iconv(
        "UTF-8",
        "ASCII//TRANSLIT",
        $texto
    );
    /* Eliminamos cualquier carácter no alfanumérico */
    $texto = preg_replace("#[^\d\w]#", " ", $texto);
    /* Eliminamos espacios en blanco repetidos */
    $texto = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $texto);
    /* Convertimos los espacios en guiones (o guiones bajos) */
    $texto = str_replace(" ", "-", trim($texto));
    /* Devolvemos la cadena en minúsculas y sin espacios */
    return strtolower($texto);
}
```

Esta función realizará, por ejemplo, las siguientes conversiones:

- `Gripe peligrosa` => `gripe-peligrosa`
- `¡España está empañada!` => `espana-esta-empanada`

Ahora podemos generar el enlace de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
/* Generamos la URL a partir del ID y nombre de la enfermedad */
$url = "includ/funcion/enfermedad/mostrardatos.php/"
    . htmlspecialchars($ROWS["enfermedad_id"]) ."/"
    . htmlspecialchars(generarUrl($ROWS["nombre_enfermedad"]));
?>
<a href="<?= $url ?>">...</a>
```

De esta manera se generarán enlaces del tipo:

- `includ/funcion/enfermedad/mostrardatos.php/1/gripe-peligrosa`
- `includ/funcion/enfermedad/mostrardatos.php/2/espana-esta-empanada`

### Obtener el identificador de la URL

La parte final de la URL viene en la variable `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]`, comenzando por un `/` inicial, por lo que al hacer un `explode()` separando por la barra, los índices resultantes deberían ser tres:

0. "": Cadena vacía previa al primer `/`.
1. "id": Identificador de la enfermedad.
2. "url amigable": Texto de la enfermendad.

De modo que puedes sustituir en tu código la línea:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, $_GET['id']);
```

Por la siguiente línea:

```
/* Dividimos la URL obtenida separada por las barras "/" */
$datos = explode("/", $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]);
/* Comprobamos la validez de la URL, debe tener tres campos */
if (count($datos) !== 3) {
    /* Gestionar este problema */
    exit;
}
/* Ahora usamos el ID proporcionado en la URL (segundo índice, "1") */
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, $datos[1]);
```

En este caso, la cadena que pongas tras el `id` es irrelevante, se ignora por completo, por lo que `.../mostrardatos.php/1/estoesunregistro` y `.../mostrardatos.php/1/esto-es-un-registro` serían equivalentes. Lo importante es el identificador de la enfermedad, el texto que le acompaña será útil solo para para ayudar a buscar términos cuando se indexen los enlaces en los buscadores.

### Palabras finales

Este es el sistema que usan la gran mayoría de páginas.

Te pongo un ejemplo con el enlace de tu propia pregunta:

- [`https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477500/url-href-en-php`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477500/url-href-en-php)
- [`https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477500/este-es-un-titulo-inventado`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477500/este-es-un-titulo-inventado)

La gran ventaja que proporciona es que los enlaces serán válidos durante toda la vida del registro de la enfermedad independientemente del nombre que tenga a lo largo de su vida.

Es decir, la clave primaria no va a cambiar nunca a lo largo del ciclo de vida de un registro (o, al menos, no debería hacerlo), sin embargo el nombre de la enfermedad podría ser editado o corregido con el paso del tiempo, provocando que enlaces que se basen únicamente en dicha información dejen de funcionar tras una edición del nombre.

### Edición final

Dado que has tenido problemas para integrar el código que te he proporcionado con tu código, aquí te muestro cómo debería quedar:

```
<?php 
function generarUrl($texto)
{
    /* Transliteramos los caracteres no ASCII */
    $texto = iconv(
        "UTF-8",
        "ASCII//TRANSLIT",
        $texto
    );
    /* Eliminamos cualquier carácter no alfanumérico */
    $texto = preg_replace("#[^\d\w]#", " ", $texto);
    /* Eliminamos espacios en blanco repetidos */
    $texto = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $texto);
    /* Convertimos los espacios en guiones (o guiones bajos) */
    $texto = str_replace(" ", "-", trim($texto));
    /* Devolvemos la cadena en minúsculas y sin espacios */
    return strtolower($texto);
}

$results = $bd->query("SELECT * from enfermedad");
/* Esto no lo necesitas, obtienes uno a uno los registros */
//$resulta = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
?>
<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><label>Nombre Pasiente</label></th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:center"><label>Nombre de la enfermedad</label></th>
        <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['rol'])): ?>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><label >Accion</label></th>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    <?php while ($ROWS = mysqli_fetch_array($results)): ?>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:center">
          <?= htmlspecialchars($ROWS['nombre_enfermo']) ?>
        </th>
<?php
/* Generamos la URL a partir del ID y nombre de la enfermedad */
$url = "includ/funcion/enfermedad/mostrardatos.php/"
    . htmlspecialchars($ROWS["enfermedad_id"]) ."/"
    . htmlspecialchars(generarUrl($ROWS["nombre_enfermedad"]));
?>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:center" class="bdatos">
          <a href="<?= $url ?>" id="<?= $ROWS['enfermedad_id'] ?>">
            <?= htmlspecialchars($ROWS['nombre_enfermedad']) ?>
          </a>
        </th>
        <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['rol'])): ?>
        <th class="center">
          <!-- ????? -->
        </th>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="regist_solicitud"></div>
</body>
```

Notas:

- Usas `$resulta = mysqli_fetch_array($results);` pero nunca usas `$resulta`. Además, usas un bucle `while` para obtener uno a uno los registros. Es innecesario mantener una copia de todos en memoria.
- El código que calcula la `$url` debe ejecutarse en cada iteración del bucle `while`, con los datos de cada fila, y no una única vez al comienzo del script.
- Tu etiqueta pone `<boddy>` en vez de `<body>`.
- `empty()` incluye la funcionalidad (inversa) de `isset()`, puedes usar únicamente `empty()`.
- Cierras `</thead>` sin un `<thead>` de apertura.
- Dentro de la cabecera no tienes una fila (`<tr>`).
- He usado la [sintaxis alternativa de `if` y `while`](https://www.php.net/control-structures.alternative-syntax) porque se integran mejor con HTML que la sintaxis basada en bloques `{...}`.
- Hay un `<th class="center">` sin pareja, imagino que quitaste algo que no querías mostrar. Lo he corregido (tenlo en cuenta).
- Usa siempre `htmlspecialchars()` cuando vayas a enviar texto al navegador para que tu página no sea vulnerable a ataques XSS.

Comment: el nombre del campo q me mencionas de la bd es :nombre_enfermedad ... en el se guarda el nombre de las enfermedades registradas

Comment: ¿Pero se guarda en el formato de URL o en texto natural libre (con espacios en blanco, tildes, eñes, etc)? Además, me has proporcionado un nombre de marcador (`:nombre_enfermedad`), no el nombre del campo de la tabla. No tienen por qué coincidir ambos, pero si me lo confirmas puedo agregar esa información a mi respuesta. Además, ¿te gusta la posibilidad de incluir la ID en la URL o descartas esa solución? La mayor ventaja es que puedes editar el título de la enfermedad tantas veces como quieras sin que los enlaces a los nombres anteriores se rompan.

Comment: el campo de la tabla donde se registra se llama "nombre_enfermedad"... en ella se guarda  ej: fiebre amarillia ... en el link deberia de entrar  .... ./mostrardatos.php/1/fiebreamarilla o ./mostrardatos.php/1/fiebre_amarilla ... disculpa si no me explique bien

Comment: si no tengo problema de incluir el id

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128789/discussion-on-answer-by-oscargarcia-duda-con-urls-amigables-en-php).